# Python Не могу вывести на экран элементы линейного односвязного списка

Tags: python

Python Не могу вывести на экран элементы линейного односвязного списка. Элементами лос являются переменные класса Book. Можете помочь с написанием метода или функции.

```
from locale import k


class Node:

    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value

        self.next = next


class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):

        self.first = None

        self.last = None

        self.length = 0

    def __str__(self):

        if self.first != None:

            current = self.first

            out = 'LinkedList [\n' + str(current.value) + '\n'

            while current.next != None:
                current = current.next

                out += str(current.value) + '\n'

            return out + ']'

        return 'LinkedList []'

    def clear(self):

        self.__init__()

    def add(self, x):

        self.length += 1

        if self.first == None:

            # self.first и self.last будут указывать на одну область памяти

            self.last = self.first = Node(x, None)

        else:

            # здесь, уже на разные, т.к. произошло присваивание

            self.last.next = self.last = Node(x, None)
    def Print(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.__str__())
            current = current.next


class Book:
    def __init__(self, autor1, name1, number1):
        self.name = name1
        self.autor = autor1
        self.number = number1

def Find ( name, autor, name2, autor2):
    if (name == name2 and autor == autor2):
        return 1


def Filling(list, text1, text2, text3):
    p = open(text1, "r")
    m = open(text2, "r")
    s = open(text3, "r")
    t = -1
    for i in range(7):
        name = p.readline()
        name = name.strip()
        autor = m.readline()
        autor = autor.strip()
        number = s.readline()
        number = number.strip()
        you = Book(name, autor, number)
        list.add(you)
        if (Find(you.name, you.autor, my.name, my.autor)== 1):
            t = you.number
    return t


print("\nДобро пожаловать в библиотеку имени Карпушиной Софьи. \n\nВведите название: ")
name2 = str(input())
print("\nВведите автора :")
autor2 = str(input())
number2 = 0
my = Book(name2, autor2, number2)
print("\n\nВведенные данные: \n" + my.name + " " + my.autor)

L = LinkedList()

k = Filling(L, "NAME.txt", "AUTOR.txt", "data.txt")
if (k == -1):
    print("К сожалению, наш поиск ничего не дал, попробуйте снова")
else:
    print(my.name + " " + my.autor + " " + k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что я правильно понял вашу идею, т.к. не понял сути `class Node` и `class LinkedList`

Если: `NAME.txt`

```
Книга 1
Книга 2
Книга 3
Книга 2
```

`AUTOR.txt`

```
Автор 1
Автор 2
Автор 3
Автор 2
```

`data.txt`

```
... какой-то текст из *Книга 1*
... какой-то текст из *Книга 2*
... какой-то текст из *Книга 3*
... какой-то текст из *Книга 2* видимо второе издание
... какой-то текст ...
```

`main.py`

```
from locale import k

class Node:                                       # ??? не понял
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next  = next

class LinkedList:                                 # ??? не понял
    def __init__(self):
        self.first  = None
        self.last   = None
        self.length = 0

    def __str__(self):
        if self.first != None:
            current = self.first
            out = 'LinkedList [\n' + str(current.value) + '\n'
            while current.next != None:
                current = current.next
                out += str(current.value) + '\n'
            return out + ']'
        return 'LinkedList []'

    def clear(self):
        self.__init__()

    def add(self, x):
        self.length += 1
        if self.first == None:
            # self.first и self.last будут указывать на одну область памяти
            self.last = self.first = Node(x, None)
        else:
            # здесь, уже на разные, т.к. произошло присваивание
            self.last.next = self.last = Node(x, None)

    def myPrint(self):                                # myPrint < - Print
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.__str__())
            current = current.next


class Book:
    # my  = Book(name2, autor2, number2)
    # you = Book(name,  autor,  number)
#    def __init__(self, autor1, name1, number1):         # --- 
    def __init__(self, name1, autor1, number1):          # +++
        self.name   = name1
        self.autor  = autor1
        self.number = number1

def Find ( name, autor, name2, autor2):
    if (name == name2 and autor == autor2):
        return 1


def Filling(MyList, text1, text2, text3):    # MyList < - list
    p = open(text1, "r")
    m = open(text2, "r")
    s = open(text3, "r")

#    t = -1
    t = []

    for i in range(7):                       # Почему `7`  ???
        name   = p.readline().strip()
        autor  = m.readline().strip()
        number = s.readline().strip()

        you = Book(name, autor, number)
#        MyList.add(you)                                   # ??? не понял

#        if (Find(you.name, you.autor, my.name, my.autor)== 1):
#            t = you.number
        if Find(you.name, you.autor, my.name, my.autor):
            t.append([my.name, my.autor, number])  
    return t


print("\nДобро пожаловать в библиотеку имени Карпушиной Софьи. \n\nВведите название КНИГИ: ")
name2 = str(input())
print("\nВведите автора :")
autor2 = str(input())
number2 = 0
my = Book(name2, autor2, number2)
print("\n\nВведенные данные:  название - `{}`, автор - `{}`\n".format(my.name, my.autor))

L = LinkedList()

k = Filling(L, "NAME.txt", "AUTOR.txt", "data.txt")
#if (k == -1):
if not k:
    print("К сожалению, наш поиск ничего не дал, попробуйте снова")
else:
    for item in k:
        print("`{}` -`{}` - `{}`".format(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вашу идею я понял, спасибо большое, но как уже без функции вывести все элементы связного  списка? Сразу после осуществления поиска и его результата просто вывести весь список в консоль???

Comment: Приведите `в вопросе!` входные данные и результат, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: Мне нужно сохранить все данные из файла в односвязный список и потом вывести его содержимое на экран. Сохранить все данные в список не проблема, проблема затем вывести элементы этото списка